# Python: Comparing numbers in two files

Tags: python, file, loops

I have come back to python after a far too long of a break from it and now am struggling to do a simple task of comparing number from file A to all numbers in file B, looping through file A to do each number on each line. The number is file A are in column 2 (split by \t) and these number to be returned must be greater then the exonStart (column 4 of file B) and less then exonStop (column 5 of file B). Eventually I want to write the lines (complete line of file A appended to the lines is File B that match that argument) to a  new file.

```
fileA (trimmed for relevant info and truncated):
    1       10678   12641
    1       14810   14929 
    1       14870   14969  

fileB (trimmed for relevant info and truncated):
    1       processed_transcript    exon    10000   12000  2
    1       processed_transcript    exon    10500   12000  2
    1       processed_transcript    exon    12613   12721  3     
    1       processed_transcript    exon    14821   14899  4
```

My code attempt at the code my explain it in more detail.

```
f = open('fileA')
f2 =open('fileB')

for line in f:
    splitLine= line.split("\t")
    ReadStart= int(splitLine[1])
    print ReadStart
    for line2 in f2:
        splitLine2=line2.split("\t")
        ExonStart = int(splitLine2[3])
        ExonStop = int(splitLine2[4])
        if ReadStart < ExonStop and ReadStart > ExonStart:
            print ReadStart, ExonStart, ExonStop
        else:
            print "BOO"   
f.close()
```

What I expect is (from my code):
Where the first col is ReadStart from file B and the next two are from file A

```
    10678   10000   12000
    10678   10500   12000
    14870   14821   14899
```

My code will only return the first line.

Comment: it'd be great to see some of your output or what you are expecting vs what is actually happening

Comment: Could you also provide input for your code that you running you code with?

Comment: How big are these files?

Comment: @RNar hopefully that have provided you with enough information.

Comment: @skrrgwasme currently working on small file but will be scaling it up to a 400M file for file A about 30M file for file B. I can trim up file A a touch to remove irrelevant information. Are you thinking size may be an issue?

Comment: No, I'm just thinking of a simpler approach that may not be a good way to go if the file is going to get large.

Comment: yeah. a major problem you have is the nested for loop for iterating through f2. since the for loop is nested, it will go through each line of f2 before going to the second line of f. you could instead read both files as a list then iterate through those instead

Comment: also, do you have file A and B switched?

Comment: @RNar I was thinking the same thing. George: You're looking at element 1 of a split line from file one, which should be "processed_transcript", not a number

Comment: Indeed I do have those files switched. What are the advantages of iterating through a list over through the file? Speed?

Comment: well if you iterate through a list, you can just use a single for loop `for i in range(len(list))` and then use list[i] to access the members. this way, you can have the indices match up. in terms of speed, it might actually be slower, but the nested for loop is eliminated

Comment: If I was to switch to a list, would I read each line `content=f.readLines()` or would you suggest splitting by \t first?

Comment: @George - There wouldn't really be any benefit to using `readlines` before iterating over it, so I would avoid it. My answer below shows an example.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the problem is here:

```
splitLine2=line.split("\t")
```

If you are using file 2, it would be

```
splitLine2=line2.split("\t")
```

Comment: I had noticed that, It still only return the first line. I have adjusted my question to include more information as request

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your file pointer. You open file B at the top of your code, then iterate all the way through it while handling the first line from file A. That means that at the end of the first iteration of your outer loop, your file pointer is now pointed at *the end* of file B. On the next iteration, there are no more lines to read from file B because the pointer is at the end of the file, so the inner loop is skipped.

One option is to use the [seek](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) function on file B at the end of the outer loop to reset the file pointer to the top of the file:

```
f2.seek(0)
```

However, I would advocate you change your approach and read file B into memory instead, so you're not reading a file over and over again:

```
# use context managers to open your files instead of file pointers for
# cleaner exception handling
with open('f2.txt') as f2:

    exon_points = []

    for line in f2:
        split_line = line.split() # notice that the split function will split on
                                  # whitespace by default, so "\t" is not necessary

        # append a tuple of the information we care about to the list
        exon_points.append(((int(split_line[3]), int(split_line[4]))))

with open('f1.txt') as f1:

    for line in f1:
        read_start = int(line.split()[1])  

        for exon_start, exon_stop in zip(exon_starts, exon_stops):

            if read_start < exon_stop and read_start > exon_start:
                print("{} {} {}".format(read_start, exon_start, exon_stop))

             else:
                 print("BOO")
```

Output:

> 10678 10000 12000
>   10678 10500 12000
>   BOO
>   BOO
>   BOO
>   BOO
>   BOO
>   14830 14821 14899
>   BOO
>   BOO
>   BOO
>   14870 14821 14899

Comment: Does zip not make it so that line 1 of file A is only compared with line 1 of file B? You get the correct output because with the truncated data it happen that line 1 matches line1 and line3 matches line 3.

Comment: That's absolutely correct. Isn't that what you were looking for? I didn't quite fully understand your written explanation of what you are looking for, so I focused on your example output and tried to match that.

Comment: @George Are you looking for *all* matches from the second file for every line in the first file?

Comment: I was just writing an explanation to you for you comment of on Roberts solution. I think I may have mislead you along the way. I am trying to find the line in file B that match my arguments for every line in file A. So take line 1 from file A search file B for matches print them. Then do line 2 for file A search file B etc. So yes I am. Sorry to have confused you, I need to learn to write more clearly my questions.

Comment: The question itself wasn't bad. You had the key points: Your code, your expected results, and your observed results. The example in the expected results part just could have been more complete, to include an example line demonstrating that a line from file A could have multiple matches in file B. Also, I would dump the last part you have about your future plans - that verges on making the question too broad since it's mainly a question about debugging your existing code. It's hard to address that part without the an answer that would be unreasonably long, or writing code for you.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will remove the extra information now.

Comment: @George Take a look at my updated answer. It explains your original issue, and should be closer to what you're looking for, but I think your example output is still incomplete. 14821 < 14830 <  14899, so that line should be included in your output (unless your code had more things wrong with it than just the file pointer).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93017/discussion-between-george-and-skrrgwasme).